# Magento2.2 - - Failed to read session data

Tags: error, session, magento2.2.6, exception

If you open the front end with multiple tabs in the browser, the following error is output:.

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/opt/remi/php71/lib/php/session) in /var/www/html/primary/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 189
```

The www.conf file specifies the location of the session as follows:.

```
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/opt/remi/php71/lib/php/session
```

The permissions for saving sessions are set as follows:.

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 53 May 14 20:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root     root     71 May 14 20:06 ..
drwxrwx--- 2 www-data www-data  6 May  1 18:33 opcache
drwxrwx--- 2 www-data www-data  6 May  1 18:33 session
drwxrwx--- 2 www-data www-data  6 May  1 18:33 wsdlcache
```

The configuration problem is complete, but an exception message is printed.
Please tell me how to fix it.

Additional information.
I also set up Redis.
The settings are as follows:.

```
'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '6381',
            'password' => '',
            'timeout' => '2.5',
            'persistent_identifier' => '',
            'database' => '2',
            'compression_threshold' => '2048',
            'compression_library' => 'gzip',
            'log_level' => '3',
            'max_concurrency' => '6',
            'break_after_frontend' => '5',
            'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
            'first_lifetime' => '600',
            'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
            'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
            'disable_locking' => '0',
            'min_lifetime' => '60',
            'max_lifetime' => '2592000'
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: did you try changing max_concurrency?  Seems like that is your issue if you are opening multiple tabs

Comment: The initial value was set to "max _ concurrency = 6".
What number should I set?

Comment: i think the rough rule is 10% of your total php processes.  I personally have mine set at 15

Comment: Change settings and validate.
If not, add a comment.

At that time, I would be happy if you could answer my message.

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure what you mean?

Comment: If the problem does not improve, I will send a comment.

Comment: The problem was resolved after changing from 'max _ concurrency' = > '6' to 'max _ concurrency' = > '15'. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: I thought that would fix it.  No problems

Comment: In my case this error was resolved simply by flushing redis cache

Answer (score 12):

Adding an answer for posterity as this was already correctly resolved in the comments by Anthony.

When using Redis to store the session data, the `Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data` error can be fixed by increasing the `max_concurrency` value.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve my problem :( still facing issues even after increasing max_concurrency value

Comment: Thanks marina and  Anthony this worked for me.

Comment: @AhsanHorani, then maybe you did not increased it enough.

Comment: Thank you it helped. I increased this parameter from 6 to 25 in the env.php file

Answer (score 8):

This issue can fixed by increase max_concurrency.

It will relate to your traffic and server conditions. In my case i'm able to solved this problem by increase max_concurrency from 6 to 24

This is all happening because of contention for accessing session data from single threaded Redis. The max_concurency config value defines the size of the queue that can form to access Redis and retrieve the session. In the event of lots of traffic hitting the server at once, some users will receive this behavior because the queue is full, so the request to access the Redis session back-end is denied. PHP session handling kicks in here and if configured correctly will start creating sessions (this is still an issue as Redis is meant to be doing this for a reason, PHP will be saving to local disk so sessions wont be available across multiple web servers etc).

This same error will happen also on the front-end of Magento2. Try it by opening 10 or more tabs of different pages; clear the FPC (or just disable full page cache to emulate hitting un-cached pages); reload all the tabs at once as above and again some will fail. This is particularly bad when you have items in your cart as the local storage is not synched, resulting in the "I have no items in my cart, but there are items in my mini-cart" scenario I'm sure you've come across.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a [Magento issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17310) about this error and a PR allready created. I hope we get the fix with the next release.